# Xcode 6.4: OS X and iOS Targets, Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, build-target

So I just installed Xcode 6.4 to start some development on my new Mac, and after creating an empty iOS project, I see the message "No OS X or iOS Targets Found". I also see a message under my project folder: "base SDK missing. But I was under the impression a normal install of Xcode also installs all basic SDKs required for Mac and iOS development?

It seems there is absolutely no information on this message on the web. I think it is not an error per-se, more like I need to create or import some build targets, but can anyone explain what I need to do to get my project built and running?

I also need to use XCode with Cordova (or PhoneGap), but there does not seem to be any clear information on how to get XCode properly set up for that. Any pointers for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't created an empty project in a long time so can't really comment on the empty project. But to make your life MUCH simpler, I would use one of the default templates and go from there. The simplest is probably the "Single View application".

Admittedly, this does not solve the issue, but it will get you going (which I assume is really what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Project menu, then Edit Project Settings. Select the Build tab, and near the top, there is a Base SDK setting.

Choose the latest iOS.

You might need to clean the project or restart Xcode.